# Add .mp3 to the end of file names

Tags: windows-7, audio, mp3, batch-rename

I moved all my songs off my phone to a flash drive. Then I uploaded them to my new phone, only when they were stored to the flash drive they come over missing the ".mp3" so they are seen as "file". If I rename each file, adding the ".mp3" the file switches back to an audio file and plays just fine but there are 167 songs.

**Is there a way to add the ".mp3" extension to all of them at once instead of one at a time?**

I'm using my Windows 7 laptop to rename the songs on the flash drive. I selected all files names and right-clicked and hit rename. I entered the .mp3 and it rewrote every file to that one title, but it didn't add the .mp3. What should I do now?

Comment: How did you loose the mp3 extension ? My phone doesnt touch the file extension

Comment: May I recommend [BulkRename](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php). There's even a portable version.

Comment: @eagle275 I'm guessing it was an iPhone?  Apple products famously don't care about file extensions, storing the file type in a hidden metafile instead, which can cause confusion when transferring files between some Apple and non-Apple OS's.

Answer (score 41):

I often use a command in Command Prompt in Windows, it's REN. The purpose is to rename a file or more.

```
ren oldfile.png newfile.png
```

But in this case, you need to rename multiple files, then we can make the command like this:

```
ren * *.mp3
```

In that, the first * is to declare all files and the second is to change all files to .mp3

Make sure you move all files to a folder and run the command in this folder.

Comment: To be specific, this will append `.mp3` to all files in the current directory ONLY (not subdirectories)

Comment: Same answer has been given by phuclv few hours earlier

Comment: @DanielW. It does boil down to the same answer but this answer provides more relevant details, especially for beginners who must wield the potentially daunting cmd tool. The simple example is also IMO helpful for noobs to understand what is going on.

Comment: But a noob is going to have a harder time finding `cmd` as opposed to `PowerShell`, which is now the default shell.

Answer (score 32):

Just run `ren * *.mp3` in cmd. You don't need 3rd party solutions in this case

Comment: Funny how powerful a basic `cmd` command sometimes appears. I don't think you can do it in a similarly simple way in bash on Linux. Though you can install the `rename` utility (not from util-linux!) and do something similar.

Comment: @Ruslan Not quite as simple, but `for file in *; do mv "$file" "$file".mp3; done` should work.

Comment: @pizzapants184 yeah, that's straightforward, but far from being as laconic as the `cmd` example.

Comment: @WGroleau if you mean Kaplan Kim's answer, it was written two hours later, not earlier.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the IOS app.  When I looked, it was labeled nine hours and yours was labeled seven.  Hmmm.

Comment: @Ruslan the `ren` command is from MSDOS command shell `COMMAND.COM`, and while it is a built-in command, in  a lot of ways it's more like `rename` under bourne shell (e.g. `bash` under linux). The `*` wild card was never actually a wildcard in COMMAND (nor is it under cmd shell) each utility has to 'interpret it internally' so it's because cmd is `less` powerful that `ren` is able to just get away with it :P

Comment: @AhmedMasud It's just a different philosophy. Unix-y shells usually expand wildcards, DOS/Windows doesn't. This makes Unix-y utilities simpler and usually more composable ("lots of small extremely simple utils"), but individually less powerful and more confusing (enjoy using `*` in a folder with files named something like `-a` or `-rf` :D). I always preferred having each application decide how to handle wildcards and I don't see wildcard expansion as particularly useful - it's more a dangerous misfeature :)

Answer (score 14):

LOL. so you have a bunch of numbered extensionless music files? Well, we can get the extension fixed so you can play the files. Also, once they're recognized as .mp3 files, they most likely will be metadata that can help restore meaningful names. But first things first.

This can be done with a few lines of **PowerShell**. If you'll please edit you question to provide paths & example names, as well as clarify if all the files are in one folder or a folder with subfolders. Are the extensionless .mp3 files mixed in with other file types?

For the time being, I'll assume the easiest, all files need the extension added & are in a single folder or its subfolders. The code is simply:

```
( Get-ChildItem 'c:\Music\Folder' -File -Recurse ) |
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}.mp3' -f $_.Name }
```

and for those that value brevity:

```
gci | ren -N {"$_.mp3"}
```

and that's it! Your files should be renamed.

Comment: how is this easier than simple `ren` command?

Comment: @eis I also thought of writing this comment, but then noticed the `-Recurse` flag, which isn't easy to do with `ren`.

Comment: @Ruslan well, OP wrote " I selected all files names and right-clicked and hit rename" so I think they probably are in the same folder

Comment: @eis my point is that this answer, being more general, might be useful for other users that need recursive processing.

Comment: Tahnk you, Russian. I could have posted the shortest, situation-specific code: `gci | ren {$_.mp3}`, but if I was only concerned with the OP, I woulndn't bother. The code I posted (in additon to solving the problem-at-hand) gives simple examples of 1) recursion, 2) use of a acriptblock as a parameter, and 3) the `-f` format operaotr. The `NewName` can be constructed from anythign -- metadata, hashtable lookup, random-number generator. Use of full cmdlet names means easier internet seraches for the intellectually curious -- "we'll talk about _aliases_  in the next chapter." :D

Comment: Furthermore, **PowerShell** is now the default shell in **WIndows 10**, finding `cmd` is a challenge for some (yes, I know the OP is on Win7). While I have great respect for experienced batch programmers, I cringe when I see someone  trying to learn batch at this point. I was a whiz with Assembler on the 8086 processor back in the day, but I accept the fact that its time has passed. The only valid reason for learing cmd/batch today ia maintaining legacy systems. Even then, any worthy pro would be updating that code!

Answer (score 6):

[Ex Falso](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/quodlibet-3.4/downloads.html) free open source audio tag editor for Windows/Mac/Linux can do exactly what you want. Ex Falso automatically identifies all mp3 files as mp3 whether they have an .mp3 extension or not. Just select all the songs in Ex Falso, select the *Rename Files* tab, click the *Preview* button to preview the results of the batch rename operation, and click the *Save* button to batch rename them.

Ex Falso is a GUI application, so you can browse to the files to be renamed and batch rename them wherever they are located. You don't need to move all the files into the same folder.

Ex Falso can also edit song metadata tags in several different ways.

1. Delete all song metadata tags.
2. Batch edit song metadata tags.
3. Automatically generate the tags from the path (for example song titles).
4. Automatically rename songs from their tags.
5. Automatically add numbers to songs' names from their track number tags.

Comment: If the tracks are properly tagged, this is a great option.  I used to do this on a regular basis after correcting tags on my music to have consistent filenames.

Answer (score 2):

**[PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)** is an official tool from Microsoft, that includes the **PowerRename** tool. It has a clear GUI, which makes it easier to use (but harder to automate). It also has some options for supporting smarter logic and will list any changes, so that you know what will happen in advance.

In your case you should perform the following steps after installing PowerRename:

- Select all files
- Right click a file and select PowerRename
- Define the renaming pattern.

  - (Make sure to select `Use Regular Expressions`)
  - `$` means *end of sentence*
  - We replace this ending with `.mp3`
- Visually inspect the output and select `Rename`

[image]

Do note that it only works on more recent versions of Windows 10.

Comment: This won't work with windows 7 (or 8, or even 10 if it's too old).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider good point, I missed that from OP's post and I've added it to my post

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **Command Prompt**?

1. Open up desired folder in windows Explorer.
2. [Select address bar](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-from-right-click-menu) and with it selected type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will open up a Command Prompt in folder's path.
3. Paste the following command in the Command Prompt:

   ```
   for /f %i in ('dir /b') do move "%i" "%i.mp3"
   ```

   and press Enter.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Best tool for that is Total Commander. It has batch rename tool with batch extension edit feature + preview.

[image: Multi-Rename Tool]

Comment: +1. Also you could do the same with Double Commander, an open source total commander alternative

Answer (score 0):

If selecting all then renaming them with the .mp3 suffix didn't work, it may be that you have the `Hide extensions for known file types` option ticked.

You can find this option in File Explorer under **File** > **Change folder and search options**
[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpyfF.png)

Once in **Folder Options**, click the **View** tab, under Advanced settings untick `Hide extensions for known file types`
[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeDiQ.png)

You should then be able to select all files and add .mp3 to the end.